# Restrict access to just some source code in Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

We have a commercial software product and we are about to hire new people to work on it. This product is in our core business and so we are afraid them to copy our entire source code, leave the company and sell it.

That said, what we'd like is to restrict access to just some parts of the source code using TFS 2010. The Visual Studio 2010 solution has about 14 projects.

We want to allow access not to every project of the solution and even in any allowed project setup what people would see and change for them.

Any ideas?

Best regards.

Comment: In my experience an NDA-agreement between you & the new people, works much better than any other means.

Comment: I agree. You should trust your employees.

Comment: I don't disagree with you folks, but I don't agree as well. People should be trusted, but we are talking about unknown people "having" access to the whole source code of a more than usd 1.5 million project. Anyway, thx for commenting.

Answer (score 7):

You can [deny permissions on folders in source control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253158.aspx). If you have projects in your solution that needs to be shielded, then you have to create a smaller solution that only has the projects that the new employee has access to.

Comment: You can setup two separate active directory groups, one for your internal devs and another for your contractors and then assign permissions as per above. Makes it nice and easy to add remove staff then and maintain the same permissions.